# Choose max among multiple groups

Tags: mysql

I am working on two tables as following:

Table 1 (Friends_Group):

```
   ID  |CUSTOMER|GROUP_SIZE
nj34nwk|  Alex  |    2
akjs99w|  Mia   |    4
qvh3njd|  Jim   |    6
```

Table 2 (Restaurant):

```
   ID  |Restarant_Name|MIN_SIZE
dwd22wa|   JamC       |    2
ssnadj1|   HappyT     |    4
facgs1a|   Bonita     |    6
```

I would like to choose the maximum number of restaurants a friends group can book. For instance, Alex group can only book one restaurant since it meets the min_size requirement of JamC, while Mia meets the meets the min_size requirement of JamC and HappyT. But Jim meets the min_size requirement of all restaurants. So the output would be 3 in this case.

I wonder if anyone can provide some hints or suggestions? I was trying to use count(*) function but I got stuck. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the two tables based on the group sizes, then group the results by the customer to work out how many restaurants each one can book:

```
SELECT g.`ID`, g.`CUSTOMER`, COUNT(1) AS restaurants FROM `Group` AS g
JOIN `Restaurant` AS r ON g.`GROUP_SIZE` >= r.`MIN_SIZE`
GROUP BY g.`ID`;
```